# Repair/restoration of plaster cracking in front of chimney?

Tags: painting, plaster, chimney, primer

I'm repainting the interior of my 1942 brick house (N. Florida). The walls are plaster, and repainting was going fine until I got to the section in front of the chimney. After removing artwork from above the mantle I noticed the layer of paint was cracked and separated from the wall. I peeled a little bit, and a few hours later I had the entire section of old paint removed. There are a few cracks in the plaster, right under where the paint had cracked. I assume this was either caused by heat from the chimney, or moisture. The paint stopped peeling off easily right at the edges of the chimney -- so I stopped there.

1. I should repair the cracked plaster first, right? Any suggestions on what to use? Perhaps a waterproof sealant / caulk?
2. Once that's dry, should I skim coat & feather that entire section with joint compound -- or just along the border of where the old paint stopped chipping off so that it evens out?
3. The plaster is very smooth. Will Kilz latex primer work well for this job? And how many coats?

Thanks in advance for any tips or guidance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wonder if you have a leaky chimney that's allowing moisture to come through the wall.